# ListView of Contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to have a ListView of my contacts.
I use Google sample code.
The problem is that I get the same contacts over and over again:

- Jim
- Jim
- Jim
- Jim
- Jim
- Anna
- Anna
- Anna
- Anna
- ...

How can I get a DISTINCT list of my contacts?

```
public class ContactsListView extends ListActivity
implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {ContactsContract.Data._ID,
    ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};

static final String SELECTION = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"
        + ("1") + "'";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create a progress bar to display while the list loads
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
    progressBar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.CENTER));
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    getListView().setEmptyView(progressBar);

    // Must add the progress bar to the root of the layout
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    root.addView(progressBar);

    // For the cursor adapter, specify which columns go into which views
    String[] fromColumns = {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};
    int[] toViews = {android.R.id.text1}; // The TextView in simple_list_item_1

    // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
    // We pass null for the cursor, then update it in onLoadFinished()
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
            fromColumns, toViews, 0);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
    // or start a new one.
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

// Called when a new Loader needs to be created
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
    // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
    return new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
            + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
}

// Called when a previously created loader has finished loading
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
    // old cursor once we return.)
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

// Called when a previously created loader is reset, making the data unavailable
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
    // above is about to be closed.  We need to make sure we are no
    // longer using it.
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}

@Override 
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
   // String  itemValue = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your line with `String[] fromColumns = {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};`, instead of

```
ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME
```

try

```
ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY
```

In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) you can read that `Data` are entries representing any number or email address or whatever, while `Contacts` are entries representing one person.

Comment: I also changes the CursorLoad uri to: 
  return new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
    PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY
                + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"
                + ("1") + "'";
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
cur = context.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection
                        + " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
                        + "=1", null, sortOrder);// this query only return contacts which had phone number and not duplicated
```

Comment: where should I add the call to context.getContentResolver().query ?

Answer (score 1):

for your code))

```
// Called when a new Loader needs to be created
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
    // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
    return new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            projection, selection
                        + " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
                        + "=1", null, sortOrder);
}
```

Comment: I get the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

Use set instead of List. Set holds only unique elements, so duplicate elements are not present in resultant collection.

Comment: Sounds good to me. so what should I do? I do not use List class at all?